# Selecting from existing Records with jOOQ

Tags: jooq

Is it possible with jOOQ to create a `VALUES()` expression from existing `Record`s without losing meta information?

Something like:

```
    List<ExampleEntityRecord> records = ...

    select()
        .from(values(/* records */))
        .where(EXAMPLE_ENTITY.EXAMPLE_FIELD.eq("some value"))
```

Currently I am using `values(*records.map { it.valuesRow() }.toTypedArray())`. However the result is an `Table<RecordN</* ... */>>` without meta information about the fields.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`DSL.table(Result<R>)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#table(org.jooq.Result)) or [`DSL.table(R...)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#table(R...)) convenience methods, which maintain the `<R extends Record>` type in the resulting `Table<R>` type:

```
ExampleEntityRecord[] records = ...

select()
    .from(table(records).as(EXAMPLE_ENTITY))
    .where(EXAMPLE_ENTITY.EXAMPLE_FIELD.eq("some value"))
```

Notice, the overload accepting a `Collection<?>` does something slightly different, unfortunately.

Comment: One thing I did notice which might be related to Kotlin: `table(records)` called `table(Object[] array)` which also does something slightly different. Kotlins spread operator is needed to do the trick: `table(*records.toTypedArray())`

Comment: Thank you. I have come a little further but it still does not work yet.

`select()
.from(table(*records.toTypedArray()))
.where(EXAMPLE_ENTITY.EXAMPLE_FIELD.eq("some value"));`

This yields an error: `missing FROM-clause entry for table "example_entity"`.

Comment: I tried to create an alias but I cannot get it to work:

`ExampleEntityRecord[] records = ...;
ExampleEntity tableDef = EXAMPLE_ENTITY.as("val");
select(tableDef.fields())
  .from(table(records).as(tableDef))
  .where(tableDef.EXAMPLE_FIELD.eq("some value"));`

This yields an error `column "val.example_field" does not exist`. I think because the column names are missing in the generated `VALUES AS` statement.

Comment: @JohannesBarop: Might be a bug. Mind reporting one here: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/new/choose